# Rrule UNTIL in the past but still returning a value

Tags: java, icalendar, rrule, rfc2445

I am using google-rfc2445 library (com.google.ical) to parse RRULE.

In the test below the rrule UNTIL is set in the past (year 1999) and the dtStart is set as now. I am expecting 0 result but somehow getting 1 result which seems like the dtStart. I am dumbfounded why it is including an item out of the UNTIL bound. Is that the expected behavior?

```
@Test
    public void testRruleExpiryInPast1() {
        String rruleString = "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=19990103T000000Z";
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        System.out.println("startDate timeZone =" + startDate.getZone());
        try {
            DateTimeIterable localDateIterable = DateTimeIteratorFactory.createDateTimeIterable(rruleString, startDate, startDate.getZone(), false);
            DateTimeIterator iterator = localDateIterable.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                DateTime next = iterator.next();
                System.out.println(next);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The above test Outputs

```
startDate timeZone =UTC
2022-02-06T18:52:31.000Z
```

Update1:
according to this answer, [ICAL in google calendar has extra event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731626/ical-in-google-calendar-has-extra-event) , it seem like the DTSTART will always be the first occurrence regardless of UNTIL being in the past or not. I find this strange. Now I have resorted to regex parsing the rrule string to determine whether there is UNTIL or not and if there is whether it is in the past.  :(

Comment: I have only seen the ISO format `UNTIL=1999-01-03T00:00:00Z`, but no experience.

Comment: @JoopEggen , I retried with `RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=1999-01-03T00:00:00Z` but I got `java.text.ParseException` .

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is a little bit of a logical corner case.

Technically the [RFC2245 in the section section-4.3.10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2445#section-4.3.10) says:

> The "DTSTART" property value, if specified, counts as the first occurrence.

The underlying logic being that the first instance is specified by `DTSTART` and that subsequent instances should be derived from the `RRULE`.

In your case since you are specifying `UNTIL` before `DTSTART` we are to the best of my knowledge in a grey area where the RFC does not specify how the RRULE instances should be generated.

I suspect that the Google library is sticking to the letter of the RFC and pre-pending `DTSART` to the list of instances without checking if it before the date specified by `UNTIL` since RFC does not mention this.